# Static IP Address through multiple routers

Tags: networking, static-ip

I should know the answer to this, but I don't think it can be done.

I have been requested by work to provide a 'static-ip' address, but I'm not always on the same router as I travel quite a bit.

Will setting a static ip limit my ability to get online while travelling? Or will I always be able to connect through that static ip?

Answer (score 5):

Ask if your work can deal with a "static" URL.  If so, then sign up with for a No-IP.com or Dyndns.com account.

These services provide a "dynamic update client" that you can use to notify the service of your current IP.

The service controls the URL, but will update its resolved address to whichever one that your dynamic update client gives it.

Answer (score 1):

You could only provide a static IP if you only used a single connection to connect to the Internet (and your ISP provided the option to have a static IP). You could work around it by using a VPN service that uses a fixed IP address, or by using your own dedicated server or VPS and running your own VPN service.

Alternatively, you could see if they could provide a VPN that you could connect to instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you search for [private vpn static ip](http://www.google.com/search?q=personal+vpn+static+ip), you'll find hosted VPN services you can log into from anywhere, that will give you a static IP. These are likely to be faster, more reliable, and less setup and maintenance hassle than rolling your own. It looks like these services go for just under US$25/month, which you should see if your employer will re-imburse you for (it's their "static IP" demand that would cause you to incur this cost, after all), or at least you could write it off from your taxes as a business expense.

If you want to roll your own, you could go at least two ways.

One way would be to make sure you have fast and reliable home broadband service with a static IP, and you could set up your own VPN server at home. Perhaps your home gateway already has this feature. Or perhaps you could get that feature by putting aftermarket third-party firmware (e.g. OpenWRT) on it. Or you could buy a different home gateway that can do it. Or fire up VPN server software on one of your machines at home.

Another way would be to turn on VPN service on a colocated server or server VM instance at some service provider (and pay for a static IP address there, too, if necessary). That would likely be faster and more reliable than the "at home" solution.

Once you consider the cost and hassle involved, it might be better to pay for a "personal VPN with static IP" service as I mentioned above. Make your employer pay for it, or tell them to go pound sand with their "static IP" request. :-)